# Creating a random integer from an array of integers

Tags: java, random

Is it possible to generate pseudo random integers from an integer array? I don't mean picking a random integer from an array, but instead doing something like

[1,2,3] = 4542

[56,89,42] = 80421

Finally, is it possible to have the output be completely random, instead of gradually changing? E.g. I would like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLkPN.jpg) not [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ACCn.png).

Thanks for any input.

Edit: I have tried using the hashcode in the following code. (The reason I don't just use random is I need to be able to access the random output without looping sometimes)

```
Random random = new Random();
int size = 10;
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
    for (int z = 0; z < size; z++) {
      System.out.println(random.nextInt());
    }
  }
}
System.out.println();
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
    for (int z = 0; z < size; z++) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(new int[]{x, y, z}));
    }
  }
}
```

For the first section of code I get random numbers e.g.

```
-733673840
2005335778 
-954776008
-695687646
-1339170035
...
```

For the second section I get numbers which increment by one

```
29791
29792
29793
29794
29795
...
```

Comment: Do you mean like using the array as a seed for the random generator?

Comment: Do you want the function to be deterministic (like given input it always has to produce same output).? Do you mind someone figuring out the function, and someone else being able to recreate the function?

Comment: If you want deterministic and not-secure function, you can create one like we override the `hashCode()` method. Say, multiply every element with a prime number (say 37) and add them together.

Comment: @redflar3 but this isn't exactly *completely random*. I'm not sure what OP wants

Comment: @addy2012 yes, exactly

Comment: @redflar3 it needs to always produce the same output for a set input.

Comment: @redflar3 I have tried hashcode functions, but the outputs aren't spread equally enough

Comment: can you please post the results of that in original post and why do you think they aren't spread equally enough, also explain with example what sort of separation you are looking for..

Comment: @redflar3, I have updated the post

Comment: In that calculation actually you are not using the random numbers which you  generated. Can you try a code where you simply iterate through the numbers in the array, multiply each of them with 31 or 37, them get a sum of those... That will give you a reasonably random number. If you want really high entropy, you may need to use actual hash functions like MD5/SHA..

Comment: @redflar3 Arrays.hashcode does exactly the same thing. It sets an int to 1 then for element does (31 * int) + element.

Comment: Then the it shouldn't be sequential like you got.. please try this `long hash = x * 31 + y * 31 + z * 31;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hash your input array, and use the single hash value to seed an instance of `Random`.  This is taken from Bloch:

```
int myHash(int[] seedAry) {
  int result = 17;
  for (int s : seedAry) {
    result = 31 * result + s;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Use the returned hash value to seed an instance of `Random`.

Comment: OP want's same output for the same input

Comment: Yes, but this isn't particularly fast if I have to create a new random object each time or if I set the seed every operation on an existing random object.

Comment: I have decided that this is fast enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Random ng = new Random();
for(int i: seedArray){
    outint = ng.setSeed(i).nextInt();
}
```

It will always give the same set of output ints, unless have changes the random number generator.